# Using IF condition to send email in sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, if-condition

I have created a ticket booking form. I'm using "FORM_STATUS" field to trigger the workflow. Once the form is saved it has `"FORM_STATUS" = Blank` hence the workflow doesn't get triggered.

The main purpose of the workflow is to send an email to the user who has submitted the form and also send an email to general office where this form has been submitted(multiple users submits form to general office).

Problem is I can trigger a workflow by selecting start workflow when an item is created.  But I don't want the workflow to send email once the list field is created. I want it to send email only when the `"FORM STATUS"='In Progress'`.

I have used `IF CURRENT ITEM FORM_STATUS=In progress` then send an email to general office.

But once I submit the form and the status changes to "In progress" the workflow doesn't trigger.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the workflow settings, in the start options, you could select the option “Start workflow automatically when an item is changed.”.

It will trigger workflow when the item is updated.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It helped to fix the issue i was facing.

Comment: i'm glad to hear that ^_^